# $f$ convex $\iff$ $f(y) \ge f(x) + \nabla^Tf(x)(y-x)$ and $f$ is convex $\iff$ $\nabla^2f(x)\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

I need to prove $2$ things:

> 1) Let $f\in C^1$. Then $f$ is convex em a convex $S$ $\iff$ for all
>    $x,y\in S$ we have
>
> $$f(y) \ge f(x) + \nabla^Tf(x)(y-x)$$
>
> 2) Let $f\in C^2$. Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex such that
>    $S^0$ (actually an S with a $0$ on top of it, what is it?). Then $f$
>   is convex $\iff$ $\nabla^2f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in S$

(I've seen [Prove this basic inequality $f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)$for differentiable convex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910945/prove-this-basic-inequality-fy-geq-fx-nabla-fxty-xfor-differentiable) but since these $2$ propositions are connected I think it has more sense to do a proof a little different)

For **(1)**, I noticed that if we take the Taylor Expansion:

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + p^T\nabla^Tf(x) + \frac{1}{2}p^t\nabla^2f(x+tp)p$$

for some $t\in (0,1)$

and do $p = y-x$ we end up with

$$f(y) = f(x) + (y-x)^T\nabla^Tf(x) + \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^t\nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)$$

If we want to prove that $f(y) \ge f(x) + \nabla^Tf(x)(y-x)$, then using the taylor expansion above, it's just a matter of proving $\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^t\nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))\ge 0$. But there are no assumptions about the second derivative of $f$.

For **(2)**, if we use the convex condition of $1$, then using the second order taylor expansion again:

$$f(y) = f(x) + (y-x)^T\nabla^Tf(x) + \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^t\nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)$$

Now if we suppose $\nabla^2 f(x)\ge 0$, we get that $f$ is convex because we get the inequality of the first exercise. But how do we know for sure that  $\nabla^2f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in S$ $\implies \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^t\nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)$?

For the **converse**, if $f$ is convex then

$$f(y) \ge f(x) + \nabla^Tf(x)(y-x)$$

If $\nabla^2f(x)$ wereto be $<0$, we'd have the second order term $\frac{1}{2}(y-x)^t\nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)$ in a taylor expansion to be negative (how to prove this?), then by the taylor expansion we'd have $f(y) < f(x) + \nabla^Tf(x)(y-x)$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1 "$\implies$"**

$f$ is convex iff $$f(ty+(1-t)x)\le tf(y)+(1-t)f(x), \forall x,y, \forall t\in [0,1].$$

Thus, if $f$ is convex then $$g(t)=f(ty+(1-t)x)-tf(y)-(1-t)f(x)\le 0, \forall t\in [0,1].$$

So

$$g'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}\le 0.$$ That is

$$\nabla^T f(x)\cdot (y-x)-f(y)+f(x)\le 0$$ or, equivalently, $$f(y)\ge \nabla^T f(x)\cdot (y-x)+f(x)$$

**Part 1 "$\impliedby$"**

Now, consider $z=tx+(1-t)y.$ We have that

$$f(y)\ge \nabla^T f(z)\cdot (y-z)+f(z)=t\nabla^T f(z)\cdot (y-x)+f(tx+(1-t)y)$$

and

$$f(x)\ge \nabla^T f(z)\cdot (x-z)+f(z)=(1-t)\nabla^T f(z)\cdot (x-y)+f(tx+(1-t)y).$$ Multiplying the first inequality by $1-t,$ the second one by $t$ and adding them we get

$$tf(y)+(1-t)f(x)\ge f(ty+(1-t)x),$$ which shows that $f$ is convex.

**Part 2 "$\implies$"**

A matrix $A$ is said to be *positive semidefinite* if $v^TAv\ge 0, \forall v.$ In this case the notation $\nabla^2 f\ge 0$ means that $\nabla^2f$ is positive semidefinite and thus $$(y-x)^t\nabla^2f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)\ge 0.$$

**Part 2 "$\impliedby$" (improved/corrected following the comments by @CalvinKhor)**

Finally, assume that $\nabla^2 f\ge 0$ doesn't hold. Thus there exists a vector $v$ such that $$v^t \nabla^2 f(z) v<0.$$

Because of the continuity of the Hessian we have that $$v^t \nabla^2 f(z') v<0$$ if $z'$ satisfies $|z-z'|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0.$ Now considering $x=z,y=z+\epsilon v$ and $t\in [0,1]$. It follows from Taylor that

$$f(z+\epsilon v) = f(z) + \nabla f(z) \cdot (\epsilon v) + \epsilon^2 \frac12 v^t\nabla^2 f(z+t\epsilon v) v < f(z) + \nabla f(z) \cdot (\epsilon v)$$

So, because of Part $1$, we conclude that $f$ is not convex.

Comment: I agree with all except the last proof, firstly $y-x = \mathbf 2v$, but also you can't guarantee $x+t(y-x) = z$, because $t$ is chosen for you by Taylor's theorem. But I believe you can fix this by using $\epsilon v$ with $\epsilon \ll1$ and the continuity of $\nabla^2 f(\cdot)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for the carefully reading. I have editted the answer and I think now it is correct.

Comment: No, I don't believe you can choose $t=0$. For each $x,y$ i.e. for each $z,v$, Taylor's theorem tells us the correct choice of $t$ to get equality.

The fix I am considering goes like this- the assumption is that there exists one point $z$ such that $\nabla^2 f(z)$ is not pos.semidef. Then there is unit length $v$ such that
$$ v^T \nabla^2 f(z) v < 0$$. (cont)

Comment: Now by continuity of the Hessian, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $z'$ with $|z-z'|<\epsilon$, 
$$  v^T \nabla^2 f(z') v < 0$$
and now using $x=z,y=z+\epsilon v$, and $t\in [0,1]$ from Taylor's,
$$f(z+\epsilon v) = f(z) + \nabla f(z) \cdot (\epsilon v) + \epsilon^2 \frac12 v \nabla^2 f(z+t\epsilon v) v < f(z) + \nabla f(z) \cdot (\epsilon v)$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I see the mistake I have made. Thank you again. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've also been trying to see where the continuity hypothesis is used in either of the first 2 proofs, I don't think it is needed

Comment: For $\nabla^2$ to be negative in the taylor expansion we must have its argument, which is $z+t\epsilon v$, have distance less than $\epsilon$ from $z$. This isn't clear. The distance is actually a multiple of $\epsilon$: $|z-(z+t\epsilon v)| = |t\epsilon v|$

Comment: I can pick $v$ such that $|v|<1$. Is this what you implicitly assumed? Then $|t\epsilon v|<\epsilon$