# $f\in C^1$ convex, if exists $x^*\in S$ such that $\nabla^t f(x^*)(y-x^*)\ge 0$ then $x^*$ is a global minimizer of $f$

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, convex-analysis

> Let $f\in C^1$ convex defined in a convex $S$. If there exists $x^*\in
>  S$ such that for all $y\in S$ it is true that $$\nabla^t
>  f(x^*)(y-x^*)\ge 0$$ then $x^*$ is a global minimizer of $f$ in $S$

I know from here [$f$ convex $\iff$ $f(y)\ge f(x)+\nabla f(x)(x-y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908874/f-convex-iff-fy-ge-fx-nabla-fxx-y) so we know that for this particular $x^*$ and any $y$ we have

$$f(y)\ge f(x^*) + \nabla f(x^*)(y-x^*) \implies f(y)-f(x^*)\ge \nabla f(x^*)(y-x^*)\ge 0\implies f(y)\ge f(x^*)$$

for any $y$, which means $x^*$ is a global minimizer.

Can you spot any errors in my proof?

Comment: Looks good - is this not the usual criterion for characterization of a minimizer?