# Convex Functions Gradient Inequality : $f(x) \geq f(y) + \nabla{f(y)} \cdot (x-y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

How do I prove that for a multivariate **convex** function $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Where $C$ is a convex set

$f(x) \geq f(y) + \nabla{f(y)} \cdot (x-y)$ $\forall x,y \in C$

Comment: Try this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910945/prove-this-basic-inequality-fy-geq-fx-nabla-fxty-xfor-differentiable?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

By assumption
\begin{equation}
f[\alpha \mathbf{x} + (1-\alpha) \mathbf{y}]
\le 
\alpha f(\mathbf{x}) + (1-\alpha) f(\mathbf{y})
\end{equation}
where $\alpha \in [0,1]$.
Subtracting both sides by $f(\mathbf{x})$ and
reorganizing yields
\begin{eqnarray}
f[\mathbf{x} + (1-\alpha) (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})] - f(\mathbf{x})
\le 
(1-\alpha) f(\mathbf{y})-(1-\alpha) f(\mathbf{x}) \\
\frac{f[\mathbf{x} + (1-\alpha) (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})] - f(\mathbf{x})}{1-\alpha}
\le 
f(\mathbf{y}) - f(\mathbf{x})
\end{eqnarray}
Let $h=1-\alpha$ tends to zero,
you obtain
\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{y}) \ge f(\mathbf{x}) + df(\mathbf{x})[\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}]
\end{equation}
which is the required result using the directional derivative of $f$.

Comment: I know it's been over a year but I want to remark that there's possible an error in this proof, when using the directional derivative, in order to obtain the formula $\nabla f(x) \cdot y-x = D_{y-x} f(x)$ you need the vector $y-x$ to be a unit vector, otherwise the formula beomes  $\nabla f(x) \cdot y-x = |y-x|D_{y-x} f(x)$.